# Multiple polymer elements in core-component-page

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

i have two elements, in different html files, how can i show the resume of these elements in the core-component-core?, when i join both files in one html file, looks well, but in different files does not. Only show the "master" element (element-one).

Component 1:

```
<!--
##### Example:
    <element-one name="ruben"></element-one>

@element element-one
@blurb Firts element.
@status alpha
-->
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="element-two.html">
<polymer-element name="element-one" attributes="name">
   <template> ... </template>
   <script>
       Polymer( 'element-one', { ... });
   </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Component 2:

```
<!--
##### Example:
    <element-two subname="cid"></element-two>

@element element-two
@blurb Second element.
@status alpha
-->
<polymer-element name="element-two" attributes="subname">
   <template> ... </template>
   <script>
       Polymer( 'element-two', { ... });
   </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 2):

The [component-page](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-component-page) link on https://github.com/Polymer/core-component-page doesn't point anywhere meaningful, so it's ironically difficult to view the docs for the thing that generates the docs. (I've filed a [bug](https://github.com/Polymer/core-component-page/issues/6) about that.)

But if you look at the [source](https://github.com/Polymer/core-component-page-dev/blob/master/core-component-page.html#L42), you'll see two attributes on `<core-component-page>`. `sources` takes an array of `.html` files corresponding to each element you want documented.

An example of this is the [index.html](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-map/blob/master/index.html) source for `<google-map>`, which renders as [this component page](http://googlewebcomponents.github.io/google-map/components/google-map/).

Comment: For future reference, the key bit from the index.html Jeff referenced is like so: `<core-component-page
     sources='["google-map.html", "google-map-directions.html", "google-map-search.html"]'>
  </core-component-page>`. You can list multiple files in the `sources` attribute (make sure it's a valid JSON array).